# MS access using case in transform pivot

Tags: sql, ms-access, case, transform

I'm trying to print a schedule using a query in access.  The problem is when nobody is scheduled for a task the field is left blank.  The problem is when nobody is scheduled for a task for the whole duration of the schedule since nobody is assigned for this task some referencing get borked.  So my question is can I use a simple CASE in my query to switch a null value on Responsable.ResponsableAbrege for something like ' ' or 'N/A' or am I looking at it from the wrong angle? Here is the code :

```
TRANSFORM First(Responsable.ResponsableAbrege) AS PremierDeResponsableAbrege
SELECT wCalendrier.Entite, Entite.DescriptionAbrege, Tache.Tache, Fonction.Abréviation, Module.Module, Fonction.NoFonction, Tache.NoTache, First(wCalendrier.PremierResponable) AS PremierDePremierResponable
FROM RecupererResponsable, Fonction INNER JOIN ([Module] INNER JOIN (Équipe INNER JOIN (((wCalendrier INNER JOIN Tache ON wCalendrier.NoTache = Tache.NoTache) INNER JOIN Responsable ON wCalendrier.NoResponsable = Responsable.NoResponsable) INNER JOIN Entite ON wCalendrier.Entite = Entite.Entite) ON (Équipe.NoÉquipe = Responsable.Equipe) AND (Équipe.NoÉquipe = Responsable.Equipe)) ON Module.NoModule = Tache.Module) ON Fonction.NoFonction = Tache.Fonction
GROUP BY wCalendrier.Entite, Entite.DescriptionAbrege, Tache.Tache, Fonction.Abréviation, Module.Module, Fonction.NoFonction, Tache.NoTache
PIVOT "D" & [Sequence] In ("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","D10","D11","D12","D13","D14","D15");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access SQL instead of `CASE` you should use either `IIF` or `switch`

```
iif(isnull(FIRST(Responsable.ResponsableAbrege)),'N/A', FIRST(Responsable.ResponsableAbrege))
```

Comment: Thanks IIF worked, altough not completely, I still have the problem concerning the whole row not showing if there is no one scheduled for the whole time frame.  Something to do with my INNER JOIN I guesss. still investigating but thanks a bunch!

Comment: I havent reviewed your SQL query closely but from what you explain I would  turn some of your INNER joins into LEFT joins